# Que répondre à « bonne soirée » ou « bonne journée »?

Tags: usage, politesse, salutations

J'ai entendu plusieurs réponses à « bonne soirée » ou « bonne journée », notamment :

- À vous aussi,
- De même,
- Pareillement.

Est-ce qu'il y a d'autres réponses ? Quelle est la plus polie, et la meilleure à utiliser avec des amis ?

Comment: A éviter en règle générale, mais qui peut éventuellement faire rire: _toi-même!_

Answer (score 17, accepted):

En France, avec des amis, j'emploie le plus souvent:

- Merci, à toi aussi (ou "à vous aussi", si vous vous vouvoyez)
- Merci, toi aussi (sans le "à", donc)

Pour répondre de façon vraiment courtoise, j'emploie:

- Merci [titre], excellente journée/soirée à vous aussi (la même en version longue, donc)

Et pour répondre de façon "normalement polie", les formes suivantes fonctionnent très bien:

- Merci, de même
- Merci, pareillement
- Merci, à vous aussi
- Merci, également

Answer (score 11):

Quelque-unes auxquelles je pense:

- Vous de même
- Bonne soirée
- Merci(, à vous aussi)

Comment: Oui généralement on ne dit pas "merci" tout court :)

Comment: C'est pourtant utile quand on vous souhaite *Bonne année* et que vous ne voulez pas la souhaiter particulièrement bonne en retour... :) Oui, je sais, je suis vil !

Comment: @Nikko : C'est subjectif. Personnellement, le « small talk » n'est pas ma tasse de thé alors lorsque quelqu'un me souhaite une bonne soirée, ou me demande « ça va bien? », lorsque je sais que ce n'est qu'une politesse, je ne relance pas la balle en demandant « vous aussi. » ou « et vous? »; je répond sans laisser d'ouverture avec un « Merci » et un sourire niait.

Comment: oui enfin ce n'est pas subjectif. On est sensé répondre "merci vous aussi" en français sinon on passe pour un asocial. C'est un site ici qui est fait aussi pour les étrangers, qui ne peuvent pas forcément comprendre ces subtiles distinctions et qui n'ont peut-être pas envie que les français leurs fassent la gueule. Si tu réponds juste "merci." sans rien, c'est impoli. C'est bon à savoir, non?

Answer (score 9):

Pour ce qui est de la Belgique (la France aussi sans doute) les réponses sont:

- Une bonne journée/soirée à vous aussi (réponse conviviale).
- Une bonne journée/soirée également (plus bref).
- Bonne soirée Monsieur/Madame (formel).
- De même (court mais amical).
- Pareillement (peu courant et légèrement impoli dans le sens où on se limite à la réciprocité).

Answer (score 8):

Je n'ai jamais entendu *pareillement* ; je ne suis pas sûr que ça existe. Quelqu'un d'autre nous dira. (**Edit:** Effectivement, ça se dit. Voir les commentaires.) Les deux autres formules marchent très bien.

On peut aussi répondre, tout simplement : *Bonne journée*, voire *bonne journée à vous aussi*.

Comment: Merci @Brennan - j'ai entendu "pareillement" (c'est peut-être autre chose?) dans l'Haute Savoie.

Comment: @alpian : Je te crois :=). Mais je ne sais toujours pas si c'est une expression régionale.

Comment: je ne pense pas que ça soit régional. C'est juste un niveau de langage un peu plus supérieur je pense.

Comment: @Nikko niveau supérieur, sans doute, mais dire juste « pareillement » n'est pas très poli.

Comment: _Pareillement_ est assez répandu en Belgique aussi, et pas considéré comme particulièrement impoli.

Comment: Oui, les réponses qu'on obtient généralement sont "bonne journée" (dans la rue) ou "bonne journée également" (en sortant d'un commerce). Est-ce qu'on répond "pareillement" au Canada?

Comment: @Brennan Vincent Pareillement s'emploie un peu partout en France, d'une façon générale. Et est d'un niveau tout à fait convenable.

Comment: Au Québec aussi on utilise parfois « pareillement » dans ces circonstances, donc à moins que le Québec et l'Europe soient considérés dans la même région, je dirais que ce n'est pas régional! ;-)

Comment: Pareillement me semble même être la réponse la plus courante en Suisse&nbsp;; il te faut voyager un peu Brennan :D

Comment: @Benjol : J'habite en Arizona et je n'ai pas le moindre sous ; voyager, c'est pas évident !

Answer (score 1):

Pour compléter l'excellente [réponse de Shlublu](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/718/1514), en résumé, le *merci* s'impose, et ensuite, un morceau de réciprocité, n'importe lequel (*pareillement*, *toi/vous aussi*, etc.)

De façon tout à fait personnelle, j'emploie souvent « ***tout pareil*** ». Ça sonne enfantin, et moins formel que toutes ces formules qu'on entend tout le temps, à défaut d'écouter ; bref, ça change. Avis aux amateurs…

Answer (score 0):

Je dis « merci, à toi/vous aussi ». J'ai rarement entendu *pareillement*.

Answer (score 0):

Moi je dis tout le temps "Merci, pareillement". je trouve cette manière efficace, peu courante (donc originale). Et j'ai comme l'impression de me démarquer davantage avec cette réponse. Et puis ça a un petit côté pompeux qui m'amuse. :)

Answer (score 0):

> Bonjour !

Mais pour moi souvent quand on me saluait « pareillement » où « de même ».

Comment: Bienvenue sur French Stack Exchange.  Beaucoup de réponses à cette question varie selon la région.  Est-ce que tu peux ajouter où ça se dit ?  Par exemple j'ai entendu dire « Merci, bonjour ! » au Québec mais jamais en France.