# Quelle est cette réponse à « bonne journée » ?

Tags: prononciation, salutations

Quand je dis « bonne journée », il y a des fois où j'entends « vous aussi » ce que je comprends. Mais il y a une réponse très commune, qui est comme « par euh main » et je ne comprends pas.

Je l'ai entendu au moins une dizaine de fois. Je suis certain que la phrase commence avec **p** et termine avec (les sons) **main**, mais je ne suis pas certain du milieu de la phrase.

Comment: Pareillement : http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/693/que-repondre-a-bonne-soiree-ou-bonne-journee

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tu as entendu « Pareillement » qui est un raccourci pour « Bonne journée à vous aussi ». Son emploi est plus ou moins fréquent selon les pays et les régions. Cf. [Que répondre à « bonne soirée » ou « bonne journée »?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/693/que-repondre-a-bonne-soiree-ou-bonne-journee).

Comment: pareillement, ou "pareil, à demain" (voire "pareil à d'main" avec l'accent parisien) qui est plus proche des sons entendus.

Answer (score 1):

Je pense qu'il s'agit de « **à demain** », car une fois que l'on dit « bonne journée », il y a de bonnes chances que l'on se revoie le lendemain si on est au travail.

Comment: merci ! en fait je suis sur que le reponse est "pareillement" comme dans le comment de @jiliagre (parce que pour moi c'est difficile distinguer le /ɛ̃/ et le /ɑ̃/ mais je suis certain du /p/)

Comment: @hunter tu dois être au Canada ou en Suisse alors :D c'est quelque chose que j'ai rarement entendu en France.

Comment: @Kiwy: "Vous pareillement" s'entend dans certaines régions de France (dans le midi plutôt). Et je cite le dictionnaire de l'académie française : *À une personne qui vous dit : portez-vous bien, soyez heureux, on répond quelquefois : et vous pareillement.*